# Maven project is getting compiled by Eclipse Update Project but not by pom.xml?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, testing, pom.xml

I am new to Maven and I have to update my Maven project every time before running the same via pom.xml or testng.xml

Whenever I run my project after Maven clean, Update Project and then Maven Test, it works fine. However, if I try to directly run with clean and test it gives me classpath errors.'
Clean goal is clearing the target and then maven fails to compile, however, issue doesn't occur if I do update project via Eclipse.
Tried updating testng and maven surefire plugin. Below is my pom

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>Complete_POM</groupId>
    <artifactId>Complete_POM</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
<suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
    <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
    <version>6.13.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>           <!https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.relevantcodes/extentreports -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.relevantcodes</groupId>
            <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
            <version>2.41.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.uncommons/reportng -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.uncommons</groupId>
            <artifactId>reportng</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.inject/guice -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/log4j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.mail/mail -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.7</version>
        </dependency>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Dependency for POI API -->
        <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/dom4j/dom4j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.xmlbeans/xmlbeans -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml-schemas -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
            <version>3.6</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

<build>
<plugins>
 <plugin>

<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
<version>3.0</version>
<configuration>
<compilerVersion>1.8</compilerVersion>
<source>1.8</source>
<target>1.8</target>
</configuration>
</plugin>

<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.17</version>
<configuration>

<suiteXmlFiles>
<suiteXmlFile>${suiteXmlFile}</suiteXmlFile>
</suiteXmlFiles>

</configuration>
</plugin>

</plugins>

        <testResources>
            <testResource>
                <directory>src/test/resources/Properties</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>log4j.properties</include>
                </includes>
            </testResource>
        </testResources>
    </build>
</project>
```

And TestNG.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite">
<listeners>
<listener class-name="Listeners.CustomListeners"></listener>
</listeners>
  <test name="LoginTest">
    <classes>
      <class name="TestCases.LoginTest"/>
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

[image: Project Structure]

[image: Maven console error]

Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: this is compilation error, you need to solve this by adding required jars and correct your code.

Comment: @Ravi i have already added the jars and the thing is that it runs perfectly if i update my maven project via right click option, but i have to do this everytime.

Comment: Small update - Whenever i am cleaning the project , i am encountering this issue on the consecutive run.

Comment: It is very clear, you are getting compilation error. How on earth you are able to run your program with compilation error ?

Comment: @Ravi i agree that i am getting a compilation error , but this occurs only when i use maven clean and then test.
If i do update project and then maven test , things work fine without any compilation error. It's like maven clean is undoing the changes done via update project process :( . Hope i was able to clear the que now.

Answer (score 0):

In your `pom.xml` you have this part:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
    <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
    <version>6.13.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

You have to change the `scope` to compile, so it will be

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
    <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
    <version>6.13.1</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Tried , still the same issue